# Select all names where none of that names entries are approved

Tags: database, progress-4gl, openedge

I have a table that contains an name field and an approved field. However multiple entries can have the same name. I have been trying to write a query that finds all unique names and decides if it has no approved entries

I feel like I need to use a join but I can only really join it with itself. Is there a function that does this that I'm just not finding? Or do i need to use some weird kind of join to make this work.

Comment: Update your post with DDL

Comment: @Notulysses i don't have much at this point, i can only really write the statement that gives me the opposite of what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

```
define variable isApproved as logical no-undo.

for each customer no-lock break by name:

  if first-of( name ) then isApproved = no.

  if approved then isApproved = yes.

  if last-of( name ) and isApproved = no then display name.

end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem exactly like yours about 6 months ago. I've used a solution like this. Hope it helps.

```
DEF TEMP-TABLE tt-name NO-UNDO
    FIELD name      AS CHAR
    FIELD approved  AS LOG
    INDEX ch-unique IS PRIMARY UNIQUE
        name.

/* Create a list of unique customers */
FOR EACH customer FIELDS(name) NO-LOCK:

    IF NOT CAN-FIND(FIRST tt-name 
                    WHERE tt-name.name = customer.name) THEN DO:

        CREATE tt-name.
        ASSIGN tt-name.name = customer.name.

    END.

END.

/* Look for at least one customer who matches name and not approved */
FOR EACH tt-name:

    IF CAN-FIND(FIRST customer NO-LOCK
                WHERE customer.name = tt-name.name 
                AND   NOT customer.approved) THEN
        ASSIGN tt-name.approved = NO.
    ELSE
        ASSIGN tt-name.approved = YES.

END.

/* Display the results */
FOR EACH tt-name
    WHERE NOT tt-name.approved:
    DISP tt-name WITH WIDTH 333 NO-ERROR.
END.
```